# does ""===null?

Tags: javascript, null

when comparing string to see if it is empty, is there any difference between:

```
if($string==NULL){
    //do work
}
```

and

```
if($string==""){
    /do work
}
```

Just wondering beacuse I want to know which one is more effective in detecting blank input.

Comment: your title and question seem out of sync--are you asking about the `==` operator or the `===` operator?  They are different

Comment: Wait, which language? PHP or Javascript? You tagged both.

Comment: What language are you asking about? The coercion rules are generally **not** the same for php and JavaScript.

Comment: his title and question match.. he want's to know if `"" === NULL`, because he wants to know `$string == "" === NULL == $string`

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Comment: ive removed the PHP tag, everyone relax and stop downvoting my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're kind of asking several vaguely-related questions here.  PHP and JavaScript aren't the same language, and you're referencing different operators in the question title and body.  In any event:

PHP:

```
'' == null          true
'' === null         false
```

JavaScript:

```
'' == null          false
'' === null         false
```

You might want to consider these tests for general "did I get something in this string variable":

PHP:

```
if(!empty($string)) {
    // do work
}
```

JavaScript:

```
if($string) {
    // do work
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a difference. Checking if $string==Null will actually check to see if the variable has been initialized at all, and $string=="" looks to see that the string actually exists, but that it just holds a 0-length string

Answer (score 2):

To test in PHP:

```
<?php echo var_dump("" === NULL); ?>
```

To test in JavaScript:

```
console.log("" === null)
```

Both produce `false`, so you can't do that in either language.

Even if it worked, it is not obvious what you mean by comparing with null; this isn't C where it's constantly used for missing values. If you're going to get a string as input, comparing to the empty string is more clear.

Answer (score 1):

> does “”===null?

No.

Behold the power of [testing](http://jsfiddle.net/kD4b7/)... for javascript anyway.

```
alert("" === null);
```

Answer (score 1):

I`am using empty() function in PHP. It is not depends on type of the variable. However, when comparing with "==" (not "==="!), NULL becomes empty string ("") when comparing to string.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, the answer is no. An empty string does not equal `null`, though both are falsey values.

Answer (score 0):

Check [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php), `""` is not identical to `null` because the former is a string and the latter is null, and `===` checks for equal types as well as equal values.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php